# php regex, extract phone numbers from string?

Tags: php, regex

i am having a small problem with my regex which i use to extract phone numbers from a strong

```
<?php
$output = "here 718-838-3586 there 1052202932 asdas dasdasd 800-308-4653 dasdasdasd 866-641-6949800-871-0999";
preg_match_all('/\b[0-9]{3}\s*[-]?\s*[0-9]{3}\s*[-]?\s*[0-9]{4}\b/',$output,$matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[0]);
?>
```

output

```
Array
(
            [0] => 718-838-3586
            [1] => 1052202932
            [2] => 800-308-4653
            [3] => 866-641-6949
            [4] => 800-871-0999

)
```

this work fine but it returns 1052202932 as one of result which i don't need .
actually i don't know where is the missing part in my pattern .

Comment: *Your* pattern? Did you write it? Then just make the dashes not optional again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` after each `[-]` is making the `-` optional.  If you want it to be required you can just remove the `?` which will make it required.  Also, `[-]` is equivalent to `-` so I got rid of the unnecessary character class:

```
preg_match_all('/\b[0-9]{3}\s*-\s*[0-9]{3}\s*-\s*[0-9]{4}\b/',$output,$matches);
```

You can also replace all of the `[0-9]` with `\d` to shorten it a bit further:

```
preg_match_all('/\b\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{3}\s*-\s*\d{4}\b/',$output,$matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

**?** in regex means {0,1} and you need exactly 1 occurence of '-' in your pattern

```
preg_match_all('/\b[0-9]{3}\s*-\s*[0-9]{3}\s*-\s*[0-9]{4}\b/',$output,$matches);
```

For more info http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php

Comment: `+` is not the same as `{1}`, it is the same as `{1,}`.  (so this would match `123----456----7890`)

Comment: there fixed, slight error to merit a down vote wouldn't you think

Comment: Not really, I have never seen a phone number with multiple adjacent dashes.