# Search for Phone numbers on web pages php or java script

Tags: javascript, php

I would like someone to point me in the right direction for my issue. I want to know if php or javascript can scan other websites for phone numbers, maybe (`<a href=+1 123-123-1234`). then pass it back to your web application if they click on the number to be able to call.. (get post) type of function? Examples are welcomed

thank you

Comment: Seems like a regular expression to find the pattern is needed.

Comment: Thank you, I not an expert, so I was thinking that if I click on a different web page that the script would not pass to my page.

Comment: Look into "scraping".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue requires attention in two sections

1. PHP **scraper** where you will give the list of urls and **scrape** them once or on a routine basis. For this feature, [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) is your best friend. Read a quick how-to guide and you will be good to go
2. In order to extract phone numbers from the web pages you will need to regex to detect phone numbers. Have a look @ [this stackover issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285970/php-regex-extract-phone-numbers-from-string) to put you in a right direction

Hope the above helps, let us know if you come across any further problem

Comment: Thank you for the information and will start looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

js is answered here : 
[Can Javascript read the source of any web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680562/can-javascript-read-the-source-of-any-web-page)

then indeed, you might have to use regex...

***sample from the answer as it is today :***

Simple way to start, try jQuery

```
$("#links").load("/Main_Page #jq-p-Getting-Started li");
```

More at jQuery Docs

Another way to do screen scraping in a much more structured way is to use YQL or Yahoo Query Language. It will return the scraped data structured as JSON or xml.
e.g.
Let's scrape stackoverflow.com

```
select * from html where url="http://stackoverflow.com"
```

will give you a JSON array...

Comment: Thank you for providing the link this is very helpful. Now I know were to start studying